# why the menu is not show all content

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, less

here s the project
[github](https://github.com/NoString/zhs-profile-website.git)
when I click the button on the top-right corner, it will show a menu. but the menu is covered.
[image]

[image]

I try to remove the Profile component.. but still not work.
then, I try to set z-index for the menu. still not work
I'm study css rigth now. if you can explain the reason, that's very helpful. thank you~

Comment: Any answer we give withot seeing the code is just a guess. Please put enough relevant code into your question so we can help. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Make sure that it does demonstrate the problem.

Comment: You don't need to set z-index of menu. You should only set z-index of main section which I pointed on my image. And you should not change the wrapper class in css.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the z-index of main section to 0. And should make the position of menu to fixed.
Absolutely positioned elements are positioned with respect to a containing block, which is the nearest postioned ancestor. If there is no positioned ancestor, the viewport will be the containing block. Elements with fixed positioning are fixed with respect to the viewport—the viewport is always their containing block.
[image: Change this]

Comment: ![picture](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NoString/image/main/note/202305171145245.png)    thenk your help, sir. but it still have some bug.  I try to increase value of z-index. but, it's still behind the <section>    I had update my code, could you pull it. thank you

Comment: You don't need to set z-index of menu. You should only set z-index of main section which I pointed above image. And you should not change the wrapper class in css.